# how to fetch form inside div using mechanize

Tags: python, html, mechanize

while working with mechanize with python, I found a major issue of fetching the forms which are inside div.

such forms are not visible.

```
>>> s = [f.id for f in br.forms()]
>>> s
>>> []
```

how to process the form which are present inside the div?

for example consider the following link :
http://www.world-exchanges.org/statistics/monthly-reports

In this link, the forms are inside div. so mechanize is able to get the form name.
how we will process the form in such cases?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the issue, can you give a concrete example?
A *form* inside a *div* element:

```
>>> br.open('http://realworldstyle.com/forms.html')
>>> print br.forms().next()

<GET http://realworldstyle.com/forms.html application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(<None>=)>
  <TextControl(<None>=)>
  <TextControl(<None>=)>
  <TextareaControl(<None>=Go ahead - write something...)>>
```

Comment: @sam: form_1 = [f for f in br.forms()][0] # and respectively - form_2 = [f for f in br.forms()][1]

Comment: @sam: unless the url is not http://www.world-exchanges.org/statistics/monthly-reports **len(list(br.forms()))** should return **2**